# Getting a client connection initated from MySQL

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to solve the problem described by [CWE-798](https://cwe.mitre.org/top25/#CWE-798), specifically how to allow my application to authenticate to a database securely. I would like to set a mysql password within mysqld and push that information out to a PHP application server. This entails communicating the new password from mysqld to PHP before a PHP instance attempts to connect to the mysqld.

(I did read through the suggested approaches on mitre.org and have some knowledge of privileged access management - however NONE of the recommendations actually solve the problem).

Unless this is initiated within the mysqld e.g. using its event scheduler, then I need to maintain some sort of script outside MySQL which will need credentials to connect - thus defeating the objective.

My problem is that I don't know how to get MySQL to initiate a client connection to the application to inject the new password; it does not appear to provide a standard function for invoking a URL nor for executing a program.

Is my only option to [implement a UDF](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/udf-compiling.html)?

Comment: mysql can talk to other mysql servers, but it has NO "arbitrary" networking capabilities. you cannot do "send msg to foo.example.com saying 'hi mom!'" at all. So yes, you'd need a full-blown plugin UDF to make this happen.

Comment: @Marc: SELECT INTO OUTFILE sends a message to the filesystem - which could be monitored on Linux by inotify and thereby communicated onwards, but this is a very high latency solution and would need 2 accounts rotating at different times to be effective. i.e. I'm not necessarily looking for a direct route!

Comment: but then this isn't a mysql problem anymore.

Comment: I never said it was - just that initiation must occur within mysqld, or at least without increasing the attack surface or just moving the problem elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

The vulnerability you're describing seems to primarily relate to applications that are in the hands of users that can freely inspect what they've been given, such as might be the case in a desktop application or a mobile app. If you have credentials in there you must take great pains to encrypt them, and then prevent that encryption from being cracked by protecting your key, but seeing as how all of this has to happen on the user's hardware you're fighting a battle you may never win.

This is how the [DVD encryption was cracked](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DeCSS), the private key for decrypting DVD data was stored in a desktop application and eventually uncovered.

Server-side code has different concerns. Here you want to avoid hard-coding credentials into your application not because you're concerned about hostile users per-se, though that can be an issue, but because you do not *ever* want your credentials to end up in a version control system.

One way to ensure this never happens is to have the credentials stored in a file external to your application, like a config file that the application can reference. Most frameworks have some kind of configuration file (.yml, .ini, .xml) that define how they connect to the database. This file should be stored on the server and only on the server, not on developer workstations, not in your version control, and *especially* not somewhere shared.

You can go down the road of using something like [Zookeeper](https://zookeeper.apache.org) to manage your configuration files but the investment of time required makes this a futile exercise unless you're managing hundreds of servers.

So the short answer here is: Don't put your credentials in your code, or store it with your code. Put it in a config file that's kept on the server and the server alone.

Comment: doesn't really matter where you store the credentials. If your client-side app is DIRECTLY accessing the database, then you have no hope whatsoever of permanently securing that access. That's why you invariably go with a middleware layer that proxies database access and enforces security there.

Comment: @marcb Oh, absolutely, you need some intermediation to avoid exposing sensitive credentials. Any well designed mobile app will *always* go through some kind of API which is presumably the function of PHP in the question here.